# Understanding Python Maps()

Tags: python

So I am trying to figure out how Python's `map()` function works as a way to speed up my program a little bit. From my basic understanding it looks like you can use `map()` to replace certain instances where you'd use a `for` loop.  What I'm curious about is can you change something like:

```
loopNum = 25
for i in range (loopNum):
    self.doSomething()
```

To:

```
loopNum = 25
map(self.doSomething(), range(loopNum))
```

Additionally, in the above example, would I be able to forego that `loopNum` variable, and in the map just have `map(something, 25)`?

Comment: map(function, list_of_arguments) runs the function on each member of the list of arguments and returns an iterable of the results that can be used in a for loop, a list(), etc.

Comment: This wouldn't speed up your program. The loopNum variable's space is negligible and map is a more complicated python function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't as `map(function, iterable)` *applies `function` to each element of the iterable*. If you simply want to execute some function`n` times, just use a loop.

Note that `iterable` *must* be (surprise!) an *iterable*, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is roughly the equivalent of this `for` loop:

```
# my_map(func, iter1, iterN...) 
def my_map(func, *iteables)
    for x, y,... in zip(iter1, iter2,iterN...): 
        yield func(x,y,...)
```

What you're doing in your code is just like this:

```
my_map(self.doSomething(), range(loopNum))
```

`self.dSomething()` must return a function or a *callable object* or this obviously doesn't work. This is because, whatever object you pass into the `func` argument of `my_map` function will be called then in addition to passing the right number of arguments to `func`, `func` must be a callable object as well :-)

*You must iterate over the iterable returned by `map` to obtain the results, otherwise, you would just get an iterable object without tangible work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to this question that `map()` is virtually never the right tool in Python. Our BDFL himself, wanted to [remove](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) it from Python 3, together with `lambda`s and, most forcefully `reduce`.

In almost all cases where you feel tempted to use `map()` take a step back and try to rewrite your code using list comprehension instead. For your current example, that would be:

```
my_list = [self.doSomething() for i in range(loopNum)]
```

or

```
my_generator = (self.doSomething() for i in range(loopNum))
```

to make it a generator instead.

But for this to make any sense at all, `self.doSomething()` should probably take the variable `i` as an input. After all you are trying to *map* the values in your range to something else.